# Why additional scopes informations are mapped using builtin Keycloak group membership mapper?

Tags: keycloak, membership, mapper, claims

I'm trying to cutomize OIDC access token obtained from keycloak (v 7.0.1) like described in this section  https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_protocol-mappers

So, I have defined a mapper to my client in order to transfer specific user groups metadata in a "groups" claim. To do that, I used the builtin "Gourp membership" mapper provided by Keycloak

And, I observe a strange behavior during authentication flow.

In response of this request :
`POST /auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=5c...24&redirect_uri=**`

I obtain the users groups in "groups" claim, great .. but claim is also enriched by some additionnal scopes like microprofile-jwt or offline_access.

What do I wrong? is it an issue ?